# Send image data though ajax, convert to pdf, download?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdf

I am using html2canvas to take a picture of my page, send the image data via ajax to php, and now i'm trying to have php convert the image data to a pdf. Here's what I have:

```
$("a[name='download_report']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var button = $(this);
    button.addClass("disabled").attr("disabled", "disabled");

    html2canvas($('#report-wrapper'), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
         var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

         $.ajax({
             'url' : "{{route('report.download')}}",
             'type' : 'POST',
             'dataType' : "json",
             'data' : {img:img},
             'timeout' : 15000
         }).success(function() {
            button.removeClass("disabled").removeAttr("disabled");
         }).error(function() {
            alert("There was a problem converting this report to a PDF.");
            button.removeClass("disabled").removeAttr("disabled");
         });
      }
    });
});
```

And here's what I have on the php end:

```
public function download(Request $request) {
    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $request->get('img'));
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $img = base64_decode($img);
}
```

I do not know where to go from here to turn the png into a pdf, and then send it back to the ajax request to have it automatically downloaded by the browser as a pdf.

I know the image data is correct because I can output it to the browser with javascript and see the correct image.

Any further direction from here would be greatly appreciated. FYI this is a laravel application hence the blade syntax.

Comment: have you tried using jsPdf to convert right in browser?

Comment: I have, it only supports jpeg, and for some reason when I do ```canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");``` the background is black and I can't change it, plus since the page is so big, putting the image on the pdf wasn't scaling right. So i'm exploring different options.

Answer (score 0):

Anybody who is still searching for the answer to this issue, this worked for me:

**JS**

```
$('button').on( 'click', function() {
    var screenshot = {};
    html2canvas( [ document.getElementById( 'main-container' ) ], {
        onrendered: function( canvas ) {
            screenshot.img = canvas.toDataURL( "image/png" );
            screenshot.data = { 'image' : screenshot.img };
            $.ajax({
                url: "/image_handler.php",
                data: screenshot.data,
                type: 'post',
                success: function( result ) {
                    console.log( result );
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
$result = file_put_contents( 'myimage.png', base64_decode( str_replace('data:image/png;base64,','',$_POST['image'] ) ) );
```

quoting the code from 'halburgiss' on this [link](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/115)